# Email server configuration problem

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, email-bounces, email-server

I used the tool here: http://www.mailenable.com/Tools/memaillookup.asp (I'm using Mailenable on a Windows Server machine) for mail.carleadcanada.ca and I get

FAIL, Unable to determine name servers for this domain. This may be because the domain is not registered. Please see www.dnsreport.com for more information on this domain.

What do I do next?  And could this have something to do with email bouncebacks I'm receiving with 554 bad reputation messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup Reverse DNS on your server? Many email providers will drop you email if you do not have a reverse pointer. YOu might have to contact your ISP to setup this.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) explains this quite well.

Comment: as well as reverse dns, also look at setting up an SPF record to fix your mail-bounceproblem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Answer (score 0):

It may be the case that you basically only have one name server for your domain.

ns1.fivetoolsoftware.com.   IN  A   64.79.69.82
ns2.carleadcanada.com.          IN  A   64.79.69.82

Both are on the same IP, so it may be recognized as only one name server, which could cause some issues as at least two name servers are typically expected.